# How to move to fragment from activity in my case

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I want to go to the home screen by clicking the button in the activity. The problem is that HomeActivity has BottomNavigation and divides it into 4 fragments
I don't want to show the first 'HomeFragment'
What i want to show Fragment is ProfileFragment
How do I get the ProfileFragment screen to appear?

I already search but it's a little bit different in my case

***This is my A activity***

```
backTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent  = new Intent(PetHotelActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

***This is my Home Activity***

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
Fragment seletedFragment = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);




    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);

    Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (intent != null){
        String publisher = intent.getString("publisherid");

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("profileid", publisher);
        editor.apply();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment()).commit();

    } else{

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();

    }

}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_bottomBar_home:
                        seletedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_bottomBar_search:
                        seletedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_bottomBar_notification:
                        seletedFragment = new NotificationFragment();
                        break;


                    case R.id.nav_bottomBar_profile:
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("profileid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        editor.apply();
                        seletedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        break;



                }

                if (seletedFragment != null){
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, seletedFragment).commit();
                }

                return true;
            }
        };
```

I want to move from A activity to show ProfileFragment 
How can i do that? 
in that case when i click the button
move to HomeFragment...

Answer (score 1):

Pass the flag to intent and get  in activity

```
backTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent  = new Intent(PetHotelActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
           intent.putextra("flag","flag");
           startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Now in `oncreate()`

```
if (intent != null){
        String flag= intent.getString("flag");
        if(flag.equalsIgnorecase("flag")){
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment ()).commit();
}
}
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Sorry.. can i ask one more? 
if want to show SearchFragment (when i click that button)
it can't not working .. what is the problem?

Comment: than replace your `ProfileFragment ()` to `SearchFragment()` fragment in second parameter of replace mtehod.

Comment: on click you can replace the fragment whatever you want. just i do in my post, you have only replace the fragment.

Comment: actually something matter occured when i use that 
I don't know why.. when i using your code 
showing error this 

    Process: com.example.blogapp, PID: 19440
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.together.Model.User.getImageurl()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.together.Fragment.ProfileFragment$9.onDataChange(ProfileFragment.java:277)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default selected item ID in your `BottomNavigationView`.

You can do that as follows:

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.idOfItemYouWantSelected);
```

So, you need to change your code to this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_bottomBar_profile);
}
```

With this code, your profile fragment will be automatically selected whenever the activity is opened.

Also, you can use the same method to select whichever fragment you wish.

You can pass any unique name for the fragment through `Intent` from your `Activity`, then in your `onCreate()`, you can check to see which `Fragment` you want selected, like,

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("which_fragment_to_select").equals("profile")){
    navigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.idOfItemYouWantSelected);
}else if(....){ ... }
```

Comment: Thnak you so much ~